# Is there a way to disable (grey) the "Send" button on IME keyboard?

Tags: android

I use the IME "Send" button in my android application to send a message. Is there a way to disable(grey) this IME button if (for instance) corresponding EditText view is empty?

Comment: set the backgournd color of the button same color as background :D

Comment: It looks like there is no way to disable the button. You can show a popup dialog with message if text is emoty. Not the best user experince solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the action to `IME_ACTION_NONE` when the `EditText` is empty.

Comment: If I set the IME_ACTION_NONE, android just replaces the action button by default ('New line' in mycase) that is not good either. We decided to use toasts or setError for the case, so it is not critical anymore. Thanks anyway.